# Randomly Losing WiFi connection Ubuntu 20.04 LTC dual boot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04

Recently installed 20.04 LTC, dual boot with my Windows 10. I have problem with my WiFi connection. When i start the Ubuntu, everything looks fine, but after some time the connection goes blind and even after restarting the wifi i can not see any wireless routers. The only fix for the moment is by restarting the whole machine.
Any advice would be appreciated. :)

### I ran `lshw -C network` and this is the output:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 5c:ea:1d:9b:3f:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=5.8.0-44-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94100000-9410ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

### EDIT:

`dmesg` output: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjaIjDC9B4VwgrEulnFfSk1iqW3U5A

`sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager` output : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjaIjDC9B4VwgrEx8bVEzV8pnBQZ2g

Comment: Output from "dmesg" next time, edit your post with that :-)

Comment: Hi, the question may be stupid, but you want me post the whole output of 'dmesg' before the wifi goes blind or you want my outpud during connection to the wireless network?

Comment: Ideally, what is output between "all is ok" and "wifi is gone". So you must wait for the wifi to cutout

Comment: Sure, i will update it soon :) thanks!

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: I updated the outputs :) during the cut out